# Why is $* not working as expected?

Tags: bash, arguments

I'm trying to use $* in a function to expand to all commandline arguments in a function, but it's giving me bizarre behavior:

```
$ function repeat() {
echo "$*"
}

$ repeat puts hello    # this gives me nothing at all
$ repeat "puts hello"  # this asks me for more input
repeat>
```

Why would it do that?

Comment: Really weird, it's work for me in bash. Are you sure you use bash and not sh ? What's your bash version ? Mine is 4.2.37.

Comment: This works for me as well, but you might want to check your $IFS environment variable to make sure "$*" is expanding correctly. "When the expansion occurs within double quotes, it expands to a single word with the value of each parameter separated by the first character of the IFS special variable."

Comment: Are you in `zsh` by any chance (where `repeat` is a keyword).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're in `zsh`, not `bash`.

In `zsh`, `repeat` (inspired from `csh` `repeat`) is a construct used to `repeat` commands.

```
repeat 10 echo foo
```

Would echo foo 10 times.

If you want to call your  `repeat`, you'd need to quote it so that it's not taken as the `repeat` reserved word.

```
$ echo $ZSH_VERSION
5.0.2
$ 'repeat'() echo "$*"
$ type -a repeat
repeat is a reserved word
repeat is a shell function
$ repeat 2 echo foo
foo
foo
$ "repeat" 2 x
2 x
```

Best would be to use something else for your function name though.

Comment: You're right: sorry.  I've been working lately on several other machines where I have to work in bash, and I forgot I was using zsh on this machine.